# How to do alignment on hex in string formatting

Tags: python, python-3.x, f-string

Is there a way to align hexadecimal digits in string formatting? I feel like it has to be quite easy, and I'm just missing the formatting. For example:

```
ones_comp = 72510
print (f"2. Ones comp: {ones_comp:#0x>12}")
```

I'd like it to print something like:

```
2. Ones comp:       0x11b3e
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
print(f"2. Ones comp: {ones_comp:>12x}")
```

which outputs:

```
2. Ones comp:        11b3e
```

or use the `hex` function if you really want the `0x` prefix:

```
print(f"2. Ones comp: {hex(ones_comp):>12}")
```

which outputs:

```
2. Ones comp:      0x11b3e
```